# Id map corner borders

Tags: texture-baking

I am painting my model in substance painter. My end goal is to be able to have a clear black border at each corner. Line this:

[image]

After asking around, it was suggested to me to do an id map like below. The person who suggested that did it in 2 seconds, but didnt want to explain how he did it ... So I am asking here. Is it possible to isolate all the edges and then bake id map based on them in Blender? I have been struggling to do that for 3 days, but each method I try isnt nearly as clear/precise as the id map below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I finally figured it out. It is not as good as the color map from above, but its close enough... Here is what I did, if anyone has the same problem:

Add those nodes in the blender shader nodes and click on viewport shading (with cycles renderer) You can adjust the border from the bevel node.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's not an answer to the question but you'll be able to achieve the result with a Bevel modifier too :

Add 2 materials to the object, set the second one to black.

[image]

Add a bevel modifier, set the shape to 1 and the segments to 2. Set the material index to 1.

[image]

Result :

[image]

It does add a bit of geometry, so that might no be desirabled if you want to keep the polygon count low.

[image]

Comment: Ah I see, never saw this method before. Yes adding geometry is abit of a problem for my low poly models. Though I can create the id map using this method and then just revert back to the low geometry. So I think this is a good option too.

Comment: @theCodeHermit You can also bake the image to the initial mesh